# Pip cannot find Package when installed with --user flag

Tags: python, pip, package

Previously I installed pip packages using `sudo pip install package`, but I switched to `pip install --user package`.

The problem is that I installed jupyter-themes using the second method, and when I try to run it the following error gets thrown.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/aswinmohanme/.local/bin/jt", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/aswinmohanme/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterthemes/__init__.py", line 260, in main
    dfonts=args.defaultfonts)
  File "/home/aswinmohanme/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterthemes/__init__.py", line 54, in install_theme
    from jupyterthemes import stylefx
  File "/home/aswinmohanme/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/jupyterthemes/stylefx.py", line 7, in <module>
    from IPython.core.display import HTML
  File "/home/aswinmohanme/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/home/aswinmohanme/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 23, in <module>
    from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
  File "/home/aswinmohanme/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .traitlets import *
  File "/home/aswinmohanme/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/traitlets.py", line 60, in <module>
    from .utils.importstring import import_item
  File "/home/aswinmohanme/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/traitlets/utils/importstring.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ipython_genutils.py3compat import cast_bytes_py2
ImportError: No module named 'ipython_genutils'
```

This is the output of `pip list installed`

```
...
iniparse (0.4)
ipykernel (4.5.2)
ipython (5.3.0)
ipython-genutils (0.2.0)
ipywidgets (6.0.0)
isort (4.2.5)
...
```

How do I fix this.

Comment: Comment if anymore Information is required

Comment: try     pip install --upgrade setuptools pip